# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'blogpost') when running NPM RUN BUILD for Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I'm running into a frustrating issue when I attempt to run my Next.js application for a production build. It has to do with my parameter "blogpost" in this codeblock:

```
import React from "react";
import Slab from "../../component/Slab/Slab";
import styles from "../../styles/slug.module.css"
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";
import { RichText } from '@graphcms/rich-text-react-renderer';

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(
  " https... ",
);

const QUERY = gql` 
  query Blogpost($slug: String!) {
  blogpost(where: {slug: $slug}) {
    title
    publishedAt
    synopsis
    post {
      raw
    }
  }
}
`;

const SLUGLIST = gql`
    {
    blogposts {
      slug
    }
  }
  
`;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { blogposts } = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);
  return {
    paths: blogposts.map((blog: { slug: any; }) => ({ params: { slug: blog.slug } })),
    fallback: true,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }:any) {
  const slug = params.slug;
  const blogData = await graphcms.request(QUERY, { slug });
  return {

    props: {
      blogpost: blogData,
    },
    revalidate: 10,

  };
}

export default function blogsSingle({ blogpost }:any) {
  console.log(blogpost)
  return (
    <Slab>
      <div className={styles.blogcontainer}>
        <div className={styles.latestblog}>
          <br />
          <article>
            <h1>{blogpost.blogpost.title}</h1> 
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Slab>
  );
};
```

Keep in mind there are more queries in the actual return(), but to keep the code as simple as possible I took it out. This code works just fine in NPM RUN DEV. But it gives me this error when I try NPM RUN BUILD or attempt to deploy on Vercel.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'blogpost')`

If blogpost was undefined, wouldn't the RUN DEV not work and give me that same error? Thanks for any help, I'm new to javascript, next.js and typscript. I've learned a lot but I'm running into some roadblocks.
Incase anyone wanted to know what the query printed in console.log(blogpost):

{
**blogpost**: {
**title**: 'QRD...',
**publishedAt**: '2022-12-10T03:37:42.781869+00:00',
**synopsis**: 'My introduction.',
**post**: { **raw**: [Object] }
}
}

I have tried a few T/S things:

1. Switched around the queries in the return(), that gives mixed results. Most of the time I do end up printing my GraphQL query without an issue but it only results in more undefined issues on build.
2. Other sources would have pointed out that I use the "blogpost.blogpost" property in the return(), however - that is the only way that the query shows itself in dev. I would imagine that works just like it would when extracting children in any GraphQL query.

> blogpost param > blogpost type > then you can get to the rest of the children.

2. I've checked my Hygraph API and all of the fields are there, and I know that the API call is working as console log successfully grabs that API in the CLI/Dev Console.
3. I could always jam an 'if' statement in there, but as you and I know - these things are defined. That isn't a solution.
4. I know it's this particular file, because if I remove the return() - the build deploys just fine.

I would expect this program that works in development to also work in build, maybe I'm missing something simple. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: DId you check your `graphql` query returns correct data?

Comment: Yes I did. I'll add the console.log output on the ticket.

Comment: https://grafbase.com/guides/working-with-graphql-and-nextjs-13-react-server-components

Comment: So I should drop one headless CMS for another? I'm open to try, do you think this has nothing to do with the javascript?

Comment: Did you get correct sluglist via graphql?

Comment: I actually do, so when I console.log(blogposts) in my "getStaticPaths" function, it returns:
[ { slug: 'the-first-post' }, { slug: 'second-test-post' } ]

If I add more via Hygraph, it should return more. Keep in mind, the slug pathing works just fine. In DEV, the title prints "QRD...", so I know it's pathing to the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had the paths: line wrong.

I had to change -

```
paths: blogposts.map((blog: { slug: any; }) => ({ params: { slug: blog.slug } })),
```

to

```
paths: blogposts.map(({slug}:any) => ({ params: { slug } })),
```

Because I'm new, I didn't realize that paths was mapping out my GraphQL query directly. Now that I mapped slug, it can be passed as a parameter. Now Dev and Prod/Build/Export works together.